# Story ID: Woman named Chagigah

Tags: sources-mekorot, story-identification

I remember hearing/seeing a מעשה about someone who constantly reviewed מסכת חגיגה to the point of knowing it בעל פה.
One day he died and no one knew about it,
when an unknown woman suddenly appeared in the marketplace
crying out that a great תלמיד חכם was נפטר, and should be given a great לווייה/mourned.
Afterwards, they asked the woman how she knew this person, and she said her name is חגיגה.

The lesson I think was about how the תורה protects the people who learn it, or something like that.

I have been looking **everywhere** for this story, no idea where it's from, feel like it's from a ספר.
Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEwVkxZE_y0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The story is in [Sefer Menoras Hamoer מנורת המאור, נר ג, כלל ח, חלק ג, פרק ה](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37509&st=&pgnum=78)

[See Sdei Tzofim - which directed me to the Menoras Hamoer](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_37023_17.pdf).

> מעשה בחסיד אחד שהיה מתייחד במקום אחד והיה לומד בו במסכת חגיגה, והיה
> מהפך בה ומהדרה כמה פעמים עד שלמד אותה היטב והיתה שגורה בפיו וכו'.
>
> "כיון שנפטר מן העולם היה בביתו לבדו ולא היה שום אדם יודע בפטירתו, באתה
> דמות אשה אחת ועמדה עליו והרימה קולה בבכי ומספד, ותרבה אנחתה וצעקתה עד
> אשר נתקבצו ההמון. ותאמר להם: 'ספדו לחסיד הזה וקברוהו וכבדו את ארונו
> ותזכו לחיי העולם הבא, שזה כיבדני כל ימיו ולא הייתי לא עזובה ולא
> שכוחה'.
>
> "מיד נתקבצו כל הנשים וישבו עמה ועשו עליו מספד גדול ועצום, והאנשים
> התעסקו בתכריכו וכל צרכי קבורתו וקברו אותו בכבוד גדול, ואותה אשה בוכה
> וצועקת.
>
> "אמרו לה: 'מה שמך?' אמרה להם 'חגיגה שמי'. כיון שנקבר אותו חסיד נעלמה
> אותה אשה מן העין, מיד ידעו שמסכת חגיגה היתה, שנראית בצורת אשה, ובאה
> בשעת פטירתו לספוד לו ולבכותו ולקברו בכבוד, על שהיה שונה אותה תמיד ושקד
> ללמוד בה

Comment: This story is quoted by the Chofetz Chaim in Toras Habayis (6:6, full story in footnote there)

Comment: @Gershon Gold Thank you! Was wondering though, how can the story be in the Medrash Tanchuma if (according to my understanding) the Medrash was written before even Talmud Yerushalmi, before Maseches Chagigah was even compiled?

Comment: @user907a Please see [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90) for when Medrash Tanchuma was published.

Comment: @Gershon Gold Ahh, got confused with the Amora. Do you happen to know where the quote specifically is in the Medrash Tanchuma itself?

Comment: @user907a Added in link for the Menoras Hamoer. After rereading the Menoras Hamoer I believe that the Medrash Tanchuma is for the previous item.