# Olam Haba Masechet

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come

I’ve heard this concept of everyone having an Olam Haba Masechet, meaning one that they master really well and are really drawn to and then Hashem will give you a world in Olam Haba for mastering it. If this is the case, what’s the point of studying all of Shas, wouldn’t one be better off just choosing one Masechet they like and keep on doing chazara on it? This Olam Haba Masechet idea seems to take away motivation to learn other things, no?

Comment: Actually כל ישראל יש להם חלק לעולם הבא

Comment: You need to learn shas to understand what to do in olam hazeh....

Comment: I heard this as well but is that an authentic concept or just a nice story? Did you see it sourced somewhere?

Comment: Would think that if learn multiple masechtos well then get an even greater share of olam haba. Also see related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/133738/your-masechta-to-enter-the-world-to-come 
and https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=32054
and possibly related https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tikkunei_Zohar.14b.2

Comment: @EraserX Interesting so yeah that first link has the story of the man only learning one masechet and being considered great. So is this implying that’s what we should do?

Comment: I imagine you should consult a rabbi who knows you fairly well for actual advice as this is way above my pay grade :-)  As an aside, I normally have heard the advantage of learning an individual section of shas very well so that if you're stuck without a sefer you have something you can learn and review בעל פה

Comment: @EraserX great thought thanks!